# C# How to use the EventHandler?

Tags: c#, event-handling

I'm just creating a ContextMenu..

At this line, I don't know what I shall put in the third param (or better: how I have to form it -syntaxly-):

```
(contextMenuStrip.Items[0] as System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add(contextUnterMenuStrip.Items.Add(exe),null, HERE);
```

on 'HERE' I have to set an `EventHandler` **onClick**

By Example I got this Method:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
//...
}
```

How could I call this Method? (Over the Eventhandler?) or do I have to make a Method like:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: You need to create an event handler that matches the signature of the click event for the button you are creating.  You'll either need to make DoSomething accept `object sender, EventArgs e` or simply call DoSomething from within your `button_Click` event.

Comment: yes I know.. But how to call then the DoSomething(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e).. in the 3rd param (HERE) when I put DoSomething it wouldnt work and DoSomething() 2 dont works..

Comment: Do avoid mixing WPF and Winforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't "call" the method but take its address. Which means omitting the `()`

```
private void menuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //...
}


// your code, I think it misses a few ')'
... (contextMenuStrip.Items[0] as System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem)
       .DropDownItems.Add(contextUnterMenuStrip.Items
       .Add(exe),null, menuItem1_Click);
```

Comment: Its EventArgs, not RoutedEventArgs.. But I did it.. thx 4 help

Answer (score 1):

As you can [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler.aspx), the callback has to have the following prototype:

```
public delegate void EventHandler( Object sender, EventArgs e )
```

So your method DoSomething has to look like:

```
private void DoSomething(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: thx and how I call this Method now in my third param ('HERE') ?

Comment: You dont have to call it. It gets called when anyone clicks on the ToolStripDropDownItem.

Comment: I had to do this, what Henk Told, but it has to be EventArgs, he use RoutedEventArgs, thats not working)... but now i done it, thx

Answer (score 0):

You can create an anonymous event handler using the Linq libraries and call your method that way. This can be a nice and quick way of doing something (especially if it's just a test project). But if you start using it extensively, it might become difficult to read it.

An example of this would be:

```
var menuItem1 = new MenuItem();
menuItem1.Click += (sender, e) => DoSomething();
```

Refer here for further information on using Linq: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb308959.aspx